# How to add a field to a FeatureLayer?

Tags: java, arcgis, esri, arcobjects

I'm trying to add a field to a FeatureLayer, this is the code I'm using to do this:

```
IMxDocument mxd = (IMxDocument) app.getDocument();
FeatureLayer flayer = ((FeatureLayer)mxd.getSelectedLayer());
IField newField = null;
newField = new Field();
IFieldEdit newFieldEdit = (IFieldEdit) newField;
newFieldEdit.setAliasName("Id2");
newFieldEdit.setName("Id2");
newFieldEdit.setType(esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeString);
newFieldEdit.setLength(100);
flayer.addField(newFieldEdit);
```

However it raises an exception, according the documentation I should to get an ISchemaLock but I have no idea how to get a schemalock from a FeatureLayer, Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: `it raises an exception` --> What exception does it raise?

Comment: AutomationException: 0x80004005 - Unspecified error, Actually I'm trying to add two fields, the first one is numeric, I can add it without problems, the error appears when trying to append the second field (string).

Comment: will this help? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110586/adding-field-to-feature-class-using-arcobjects-and-c

Comment: For a start, the featurelayer interface has no method called "addfield", this is a method on the featureclass interface, so your last line should be:  flayer.featureclass.addField(newFieldEdit)